# Selenium webdriver NUnit C# - How to disable opening firefox in safe mode?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Implicitly the test are run in Firefox safe mode and I need to disable this. I have looked for ways of doing this, but I couldn't find any.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes", "-1");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

`profile` is not recognized as if it wasn't declared. Here is my code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.SetPreference("toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes", "-1");
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    }
}
```

The error for `profile` is:

> 'Test.Class1.profile is a field but is used like a 'type'

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Selenium, but rather a basic C# question.

You don't have an entry point, such as a Main method. If this is a DLL (such as a library to be used with NUnit or MSTest), you need to use the attributes to define tests - such as `TestFixture`.